# Bootstrap row with nested columns margin issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

If i use 4 columns across, there is no issue as in the first example.  But if I insert a row of size 8 with 2 columns inside between 2 size columns, the columns are not as wide as the first example even though it adds up to 12?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">Column A</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:palegreen;">Column B</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style=" background-color:palegoldenrod;">Column C</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lightpink">Column D</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" style="width:100%;background-color:blue;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md4 col-lg-3" style="background-color:lavender;">Column A</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-6 row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-12" style="background-color:palegreen;">Column B</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-12" style="background-color:palegoldenrod;">Column C</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-md-4" style="background-color:lightpink">Column D</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you are using the `col-*` you will have to wrap them inside the `row` div.

```
...
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">Column B</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">Column C</div>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Notice also that I removed all the `col-*-12` as you can simply skip them and if there are sizes that have the same col-span then you should just keep the smallest one, the rest are redundant.

You can also verify that on their official [example for grids](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

Comment: Thanks, please see [link](http://jsfiddle.net/b504jf3L/) Is there padding i need to add as columns b and c still smaller?

Comment: you have a `col` in the class with `col-*` which is a really bad thing.. here is the fixed one.. http://jsfiddle.net/b504jf3L/1/

Comment: I just saw that I had it by copy pasting here as well.. updated the code